# Chomsky Normal Form Transformation

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I've been struggling a bit with creating the Chomsky normal form derivation of a grammar that I have been given

The grammar in question is:

$S \to BB \mid 0A0 \mid 1B1 \\
A \to C \\
B \to S \mid \varepsilon \\
C \to S \mid A$

So far I have ended up with

$S0 \to S \\
S \to BB \mid 0A0 \mid 1B1 \mid 00 \mid 11 \\
A \to BB \mid 0A0 \mid 1B1 \mid 00 \mid 11 \\
B \to BB \mid 0A0 \mid 1B1 \mid 00 \mid 11 \\
C \to BB \mid 0A0 \mid 1B1 \mid 00 \mid 11$

I assume i am doing something horribly wrong, when doing eliminating unit transitions; would anybody be able to give me a clear explanation of the steps taken?

Thank you!

Comment: First you should note that $C$ appears only once on the right, so you could substitute all "outcomes" of $C$ into the right side of the derivation of $A$. Then note that the resulting rule $A\rightarrow S|A$ is equivalent to $A\rightarrow S$ and now $A$ can be eliminated all together by substituting it by $S$. Can you do the rest yourself?

Comment: @MHS I ended up with S0 -> S, S -> SS/FD/GE/DD/EE/epsilon, D -> 0, E -> 1, F -> DS, G -> ES    Just wanted to check whether this was right, thank you very much for the help!